# trying to bind jquery(document).click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to bind $(document).click event in asp.net ajax  BeginrequestHandler and EndRequestHandler event when the Request is sent the unbind should be called so that the click event does not work. When the endRequestHandler is called then the bind should be executed again.

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
     {
       $(document).unbind("click");
       $("#divUtility > :first-child").css({
        'position':'absolute', 
        'left':'0px', 
        'right':'0px', 
        'width':'250px', 
        'height':'70px', 
        'background-color':'#EfEfEF'
       });
     }


   function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
   {
      $(document).bind("click",function(e){
       if($(e.target).hasClass("UtilityClass"))
       { 
       }
       else
       {
         $('.popupstyle').hide();
       }
      });
   }
```

The rest is working fine.However, the unbind is not working.

Comment: yes it is called. The code block of css in there is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The first task to do is to put some

```
console.debug("your message")
```

in your function

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
```

in order to check if the callback is really called.

Secondly, you should use namespace on your click in order to avoid removing ALL event handler on the click event (even not yours). Add you event handler with

```
$(document).bind("click.myNameSpace", function(mouseEvent) {
    // your code here
});
```

and remove your event handler with

```
$(document).unbind("click.myNameSpace");
```

Comment: did you try to comment the code in the EndRequestHandler(sender, args) and check if the event handler is always bound